# How would I go extending timber to be able to use handles as references in includes?

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

We use fractal.js with a twig engine to prototype websites. Fractal.js brings a handy functionality to be able to use handles in includes.

So instead of writing `{% include 'templates/components/teaser/basicTeaser.twig' %}`, you can just write `{% include '@basicteaser' %}`. See: https://fractal.build/guide/core-concepts/naming.html#referencing-other-items

Of course that relies on unique components names, which I am happy to have anyway.

Could anybody point me in the right direction on how to extend timber or twig to use such handles?

Many thanks!

Comment: Actually fractal does not use twig, but handlebars. That makes it somewhat different in functionality, even if the language looks equally mustache-y

Comment: @sascha I'm wondering if you ever figured this out. We use CraftCMS and Fractal and have a similar loader. We're trying to port to WordPress and it's proving to be trickier than we expected.

Answer (score 1):

Twig already offers the option to load templates from an array of directories rather than just one.

```
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader([$templateDir1, $templateDir2]);
```

Plus, before passing the loader to the environment object, you can add paths for custom namespaces, i.e.:

```
$loader->addPath($templateDir, 'admin');
```

Then you can use you namespace like this:

```
$twig->render('@admin/index.html', []);
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#built-in-loaders

Comment: But I do not want to specify the location of the file. Just be able to add the handle derived from the filename and its location and use this. I am aware that the file names need to be unique for this to work. Likely I would need to go over each file and add that handle somehow, but I do not know how to do this.
I also do not want to use the file extension in the include.

Comment: Maybe you must provide your own loader then: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#create-your-own-loader it would allow to specify your own naming and even provide the template source from a database, or whatever you can retrieve the template source.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and this might not be relevant to the OP anymore, but we needed the same thing and [developed a WordPress plugin](https://github.com/madebyraygun/Fractal-Timber-Loader-for-WordPress) to bridge Timber + Fractal. You can export your Fractal components to the `components-map.json` file, then the loader will read the map and convert those component names to file paths.

Comment: Edit: I was getting an error fresh out of the box: `Fatal error: Class TwigFractalLoader contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Twig\Loader\LoaderInterface::getSource)`

And we solved it updating a Twig version in timber wordpress plugin.
Works like a charm, thank you!